# Add an Authorized redirect URI to GCloud OUaht Client from terminal

Tags: google-oauth, gcloud

We have a test GCloud OAuth app, and I'd like to add&remove extra redirect URIs to it from the CLI.

We have a Gitlab CI/CD job that creates a review env for our stack -> and we have apps that use Google Login in this stack. These review envs run on k8s, and each one of the envs have a unique URL.

It'd be nice if we could add the valid redirect URI to Google's config when the review env is created & remove this URL when the MR is closed. But I cannot found any gcloud cli app which can do this.

Is there any gcloud utils which can modify the OAuth2 Client app configs on the gcloud?

Comment: I think there isn't any public API for managing OAuth2 Client IDs. You can observe Developer Tools while making changes to OAuth2 Client IDs to verify whether there are any endpoints that are exposed but I think this is likely unavailable.